# Computing a normal to a plane using cross product

Tags: plane-geometry, plane-curves

I have a plane $ ax + by +cz = 0 $.  I know that the normal to the plan is the 3 dimensional vector $(a,b,c)^T $ because I define $ f(x,y,z) = ax + by +cz $ and the normal vector is $ \nabla  f $

Now I want to do it in another way - I parameterized the plane in this way $$ \vec {s}(x,y) =(ax,by,-(ax +by)/c )^T
$$

$\vec{s}_x = (a,0,-a/c)^T   $

$\vec{s}_y = (0,b,-b/c)^T   $

From what I read the normal vector should be $ \vec{s}_x \times \vec{s}_y $ but when I compute it I don't get the vector $(a,b,c)^T$

Any idea where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1):

The normal vector of a plane is not unique. There is a whole line of normal vectors. The one you get by taking the cross product and the one given by one implicit equation must be proportional in any case.

Comment: But what I get it is not some constant times $ (a,b,c)^T $ so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I see now that your vectors $s_x, s_y$ are not lying on the plane. They don't verify the equation. Take $s_x = (-c, 0, a)$ and $s_y = (0, c, -b)$ instead.

Comment: Yes thanks!  I should have   $ s(x,y) = (x,y,-(ax+by)/c)^T $  as my plane.